# How to serve a file split in parts in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to serve a big file split in multiple parts as a single file in my django view. Is there a way to do that dynamically without having to load all the chunks in memory?

Comment: What have you tried? If you want to send `n` files as a big one, you will have to concatenate them at some point, so read them, hence a buffer in memory.

Comment: Yeah, that's the straightforward way to do that. However, having at any point all of them concatenated in memory is not possible. I am looking for a way to serve these files in a streaming fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You probable would like to use FileObject:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File